# Disable click on a 3rd party application

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm writing an application that needs to record a click location on the screen, over the top of another window using the mouse. Is there anyway to disable the mouse click so that it doesn't affect the window that is being clicked over?

e.g. I want to set a point over the top of my browser, but I don't want to click anything within my browswer whilst setting it.

Comment: What does it mean to "set a point on the screen?"

Comment: Sorry, I just want to record the click position - nothing more (in the scope of thjs question).

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing. Your comment says you want to know how to record mouse activity. But your question is about disabling clicking? I don't see the relation between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1. Write a plugin/extension for the browser you're talking about. Maybe the browser's interface allows you to record such information
2. Use windows hooks. Using `SetWindowsHookEx` and `WH_MOUSE_LL`, you can get all mouse activity on the computer fairly simply. You will just need to check if the mouse activity is happening in the browser, using [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).